# php form and session assignment in the same file

Tags: php

I am trying to use post in a form to save form data from a dropdown as a session in the same file as the form

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid']))
  unset($_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid']);
?>
```

Then in the body of html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
include 'connect.inc';

$sql = "SELECT surnameid FROM customer";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='surnameid'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['surnameid'] . "'>" . $row['surnameid'] .    </option>";
}
include 'close.inc';
?>

<br/> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
<?php    
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;

echo $_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid'];
?>
```

The assiginment to $_SESSION does not work

Comment: How does it not work? When you `echo $_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid'];`, it prints nothing? What is the result?

Comment: you forgot a " when you close the </option> when you echo the options . Try :     echo "<option value='" . $row['surnameid'] . "'>" . $row['surnameid'] .    "</option>";

Answer (score 1):

Try this : 
You forgot a double quote when you are putting echoing

make sure that you have the rows in the database ( we can't test that ) but i tested with predefined data and this version works

**form.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();

?>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php

echo "<select name='surnameid'>";
    echo "<option value='1'>test</option>";
    echo "<option value='2'>test2</option>";

?>

<br/> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
<?php    

if( !empty($_POST)){
    $_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
}


if(isset($_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid']))
echo $_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid'];
?>
```

test_session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid']);

?>
```

Comment: The last echo statement does not work and I cannot get echo $_SESSION['post-data']['surnameid']; to work in another file i get undefined variable error I have used session_start(); as first php statement.

Comment: I edited, and i just retested everything right now and it's working perfectly ( i put all the file this time ), please let me know

Comment: Hi partial success form.php works as expected, prints 1. test_session fails with error, Notice: Undefined index: post-data in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test_session.php on line 3. Between running these files i have not restarted firefox. Have also tried echo in test_session, same error.

Comment: are you sure you added session_start() ? also did you run first form.php then test_session.php ?

Comment: Hi have done a var_dump($_SESSION); in test_session and get array(0) { }. Therefore I think the session is not being picked up. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, i put all the code now, both from form.php and test_form.php , i retested it and it works on my end. can you confirm that this code works?

Comment: Today I am looking at the php.ini file to check the session settings are correct and can you tell me if cookies on or off????

Comment: I'm using xampp on localhost and sessions are a commom problem.

Comment: it's most probably . If everything is setup correctly, the code shouldn't be any problem

Comment: I have turned on session.auto_start = 1 as my program is on localhost with a browser front end. I cannor use session_start in any script.